# Set view size after ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, view, size, scale, objectanimator

I have an ImageView which I scale it using ObjectAnimator. Its original size is 220px, and I scale it to 33px, but the problem is that when the animation finishes, the image looks like it is 33px, but if I get its size, it returns me 220px, and if I try to scale it to 33px after the animation is finished it just disappears.

If I change its size to 220px after the animation is finished it doesn't change, like if the ImageView would still be 220px but the image inside and the view's background would be 33px and because of that, when I scale it to 33px, the image and background are even smaller and can't be seen.

What can I do to set the views size to real 33px after animation finishes? :p

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=objectanimator+size&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8